# Material UI global css variables

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, css-in-js

I would like to declare some css variables that I will reuse among my components. This is how you do it with plain css:

```
:root {
  --box-shadow: 0 2px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

That would then be used as follows:

```
.my-class {
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
}
```

How can I achieve the same with useStyles? I tried the following with no avail:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  shadowing: {
    boxShadow: "0 2px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)",
  }
});
```

My main App is enclosed within

```
<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
  <App />
</ThemeProvider>
```

I tried using it in my component:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  workImage: {
    boxShadow: theme.shadowing,
  },
}));
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"createMuiTheme" function accepts object with limited set of keys.(palette, Typography, spacing...etc)

You can use just normal object.

```
const theme = {
  shadowing: {
     boxShadow: "0 2px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)",
  }
};
```

Answer (score 9):

In my case I had to use both createMuiTheme and custom variables. To achieve it I did as follows.

First I created a theme with createMuiTheme

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: "verdana",
  },
});
```

Then I created a separated object where I add my variables:

```
const cssVariables = {
  shadowing: {
     boxShadow: "0 2px 5px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)",
  }
};
```

Then I pass the two objects to my ThemeProvider:

```
<ThemeProvider theme={{ ...theme, ...cssVariables }}>
```

And finally, to access the variable:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  workImage: {
    boxShadow: theme.shadowing.boxShadow,
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved that by declaring a js const with the value and assigning it to the CSS property:

```html
const color = "red";

    const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) =>
        createStyles({
            root: {
            color: color
            }
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Material UI (v5.6.0) now supports CSS variables as an *experimental* feature ([docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/experimental-api/css-theme-variables/overview/)).